# cannot find method setModal(boolean)

Tags: java, swing

Why can't I call the `setModal()` method?

I am working on GUI.  I have two jframes.  The following code is for a button and is supposed to open the other frame. But i get error that says:

> cannot find method setModal(boolean)

```
 private void jButton3_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
            HR hr = new HR(); 
            if(f == 1){  // condition
            hr.setModal(true); // give me error here ?
            hr.setVisible(true);    
            }else{
                jLabel5.setText("You aren't connected...");
            }
    }
```

hr.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class HR extends JFrame {
    public HR() {
        try {
            jbInit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void jbInit() throws Exception {
        this.getContentPane().setLayout( null );
        this.setSize( new Dimension(400, 300) );
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `HR`? What makes you think that this type should have `setModal(boolean)` method?

Comment: can you show us the HR class

Comment: I see `setModel` in the pasted code instead of `setModal`?

Comment: i need when user click the button once it open anew frame . and cann't click at the any part in first frame

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am working on GUI I have two jframes

An application should only have a single parent `JFrame`. Other child windows should be a `JDialog` and you specify the frame as the parent.

A `JDialog` DOES have the `setModal(...)` method.

You create a `JDialog` the same way you create a `JFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

**JFrame** class has no `setModal(boolean)` method.. 
refer to the doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)

therefore you CAN NOT invoke that method, your **HR** class must instead have defined that method... but I see in the update that actually the HR class is not defining it...

Comment: thanks for help,
i think i found the answer
it's supposed to extend JDialog not JFrame